# Function to generate automatic header

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to create a jQuery script that gets the first 5 words of a textarea's text and paste it in an input (something like header of a topic, but generated from the textarea content). I've already created the script that gets the first 5 words and pastes them, but I want to do a function that detects when the input was changed manually (by the user) or through the script (for the 5 words) so I can enable/disable the script. In short I want to achieve when the input is changed manually (by the user) no matter what the user is adjusting in the textarea - the input should not change anymore by the script (it must remain as edited as it is by the user). Any idea how to achieve that? Here's what I already have:

```
     $('#textarea').bind('input keyup', function() {
        var contentVal = $('#textarea').val();
        var contentValSplit = $('#textarea').val().split(' ');
        var headerVal = $('#input').val().split(' ');
        if(headerVal.length > 5) {
            if(contentValSplit.length < 6) {
                $('#input').val(contentVal);
            } else if($('#textarea').val() == "") {
                $('#input').val('');
            }
        } else {
            $('#input').val(contentVal + "...");
        }
     });
```

Comment: Add a `change` or `input` handler to your input field (those only trigger when the user changes the field value, not when it happens via script) - and then inside the callback function for that, remove the above handler function from the textarea again.

Comment: And FYI. `.bind` is deprecated. You should use `.on` to add event handlers in current code. https://api.jquery.com/on/ The counterpart to remove an event handler from an element, is `.off``

Comment: @CBroe `$('#input').on('input', function() { $('#input').off(); });` **this doesn't work**

Comment: I said you should remove the handlers from the textarea, not the input field. And just calling `.off()` without any parameters, will remove _all_ event handlers you might have bound to that element, not sure if you want that.

Comment: `.off()` is exactly what I want, but I still cannot understand how to do what I want.

Comment: The event handlers that you have added to the textarea, are the ones that are manipulating the content of your input field. So if you want that to stop ... well then remove those event handlers from the textarea. What's not to understand about that ...?

Comment: Alright, thank you. I manage to do it.

Comment: There is another problem. When i directly paste a text to the textarea it also pastes the whole text in the input (not only the first 5 words). Any idea how do I Fix that?

Comment: That would presumably be the fault of the `$('#input').val(contentVal)` line - meaning, your conditions it depends on, aren't correct.

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to do there, with the combination of `headerVal.length > 5` and `contentValSplit.length < 6`? Setting the full textarea content, when it is less than 6 parts, okay - but what is the with the condition above that, checking if the input contained more than 5 parts already ...?

Comment: So it should not continue pasting text after having more than 5 parts

Comment: But isn't that backwards then? `headerVal.length > 5` makes it go into that branch only if there are already more than 5 parts.

Comment: No. I'm explaining: imagine I typed text in the textarea and the script already typed the first 5 words in the input. Then for example I'm deleting the textarea's text literally to the fifth word - that is OK for now right? But if i continue deleting from the textarea it wont change the input with the actual words. That's where the condition appears so it can always get the first 5 words no matter when typed in the textarea.

Comment: If you are removing words from the textarea, then `contentValSplit` would become less than 5 at some point. But why are you checking `headerVal.length > 5` then?

Comment: Follow the logic. Begin with **When #textarea gets changed -> If the length (in words) of the input is more than 5 -> (AND) If the length (in words) of the textarea is no more than 6 (5) -> Continue getting the value of the textarea and pasting it in the input**. I cannot explain it much better. When I remove the following condition `if(contentValSplit.length < 6) { $('#review_header').val(contentVal); }` and I start removing words from the textarea - the text doesnt appear in the input. They only appears at first typed-in text.

Comment: `If the length (in words) of the input is more than 5`- what sense is that supposed to make? You said from the very start, that you wanted to put the **first five** words from the textarea into the input field. So why does it _continue_ at this point, if the input field _already_ contains more than five words?

Comment: Because if i don't do these checks the script will continue to paste text from the textarea in the input and nothing can stop it.

Comment: But if the input field _already_ contains more than five words, you go into the else branch, where you append the _complete_ content of the textarea + "..." - what sense is that supposed to make? I can't even say which is more confusing here - your attempt at explaining what you _actually_ want, or the code you have written.

Comment: So which is the right way to do this?

Comment: _"but I want to do a function that detects when the input was changed manually (by the user) or through the script (for the 5 words) so I can enable/disable the script."_ - the first part of that we already covered - when the user changes the input field content manually, then remove the event handler from the textarea. And the second part - well once you determined _inside_ your textarea handler, that you _have_ already written five words to the input, do the same thing - remove the event handler from the textarea, so that it does not fire again.

Comment: Everything works great, the problem now is that when I paste a text in the textarea the script literally pastes the same text in the input and we don't want that. We need only the first 5 words of the pasted text.

Comment: Well then insert only those first five words, instead of the _complete_ textarea content, which is what you are inserting now ... You have not actually _done_ anything yet (or at least nothing that actually makes sense), to limit this to just five words.

Comment: `contentValSplit` is an array with all the words - so pick the first five from that (hint: Array.slice method), join them together with a space in between, and then assign _that_ to your input field.

Comment: But how do I control "on paste" of the textarea inside the if condition?

Comment: I don't know what you want to "control" there. The `input` event already covers pasting new content into the textarea, so your handler function already gets called. Why/how do you think the textarea content would need to be _handled_ differently now, based on whether the user actually typed, or just copy&pasted it?

Comment: When the user paste a text to the textarea the script literally pastes the same text in the input and we don't want that. We want only the first 5 words of the pasted text. I don't know how to explain it more easier to you.

Comment: And I don't know how to explain any clearer, that this _should_ not require any different logic, than you would use in case the user was typing that same content. But you need to get the logic right to begin with, and as said, I don't see your current conditions and how they are nested make much sense in that regard.